# On which side resides the rejection area of a Chow test?

Tags: chow-test

I know Chow test, it computes a test statistic, and the test statistic follows F distribution, but I don't know on which side does the null hypothesis reject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null hypothesis (h0) is that the parameters are equal . The alternative(h1) is that they are not equal.

Comment: Indeed: but it looks like the OP might appreciate your elaboration of what that means in terms of the $F$ statistic (although that implication is obvious to you). They are surely wondering whether a *small* value of that statistic ought to be considered evidence against the null.

Comment: If the F value that is compued is "small" then that means (to me) that the null hypothesis is "very acceptable" since if the parameters for each group are identical then the computed F value would be identically 0.0 . I don't see a small F being considered as evidence that the null is wrong but rather "proof" that the null is true.